# Error while making t test - Problem selecting the variables

Tags: r, t-test

Im trying to do a t test between two means of a test of two groups but I have been unable to get a result. Im receieving this error

`Warning in is.na(y) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language' Error: ! Can't combine` SpeakGroup`<character> and`GmeanResponse` .
Backtrace:

1. deledata %>% ...
2. stats:::t.test.default(...)
3. tibble:::`[.tbl_df`(x, xok)
4. tibble:::tbl_subset_matrix(x, j, j_arg)
5. vctrs::vec_c(!!!values, .name_spec = ~.x)
6. vctrs (local) `<fn>`()
7. vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
8. vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
9. vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
10. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)`

This is the code im using:

```
deledata <- groupwithmean %>%
  filter(Test == "ESP")
deledata
```

The output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MGXQ.png)

and the code for the t test

```
ttestDELE <- deledata %>%
  t.test(GmeanResponse ~ SpeakGroup, mu=0, alt="two.sided", conf=0.95, var.eq=F, paired=F)

ttestDELE
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only thing we need to help you is the data. So in your console paste `dput(deledata)`. Copy the output and paste it to your question via the Edit button below the question. Then tell us which one is the value and which one is the group to test.

Comment: You are missing the data argument, try `deledata %>% t.test(GmeanResponse ~ SpeakGroup, data = ., etc)`.